# How to split string according to two conditions at the beginning and end of a sentence simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string like,

```
str1 = "ZZZ。10月,AAA。11月2日,BBB。CCC。3日,DDD。EEE。12月，FFF"
```

And I want to split this string by two conditions: `日` or `月` appear at the begining of string, at the same time, period `。`at the end of string. Thus, the result should like,

```
# ZZZ。 / 10月,AAA。/ 11月2日,BBB。CCC。/3日,DDD。EEE。/12月，FFF
```

And now, my idea is split them by period at first, then combine each of them according to the second rules(`日` or `月`), the code can be run like,

```
import re
str1 = "ZZZ。10月,AAA。11月2日,BBB。CCC。3日,DDD。EEE。12月，FFF"

for i, item in enumerate(re.split(r'(?<=。)',str1)):
    if i == 0:
        cache = item 
    else:
        if re.match(r'(^.{0,2}日)|(^.{0,2}月)', item):
            res.append(cache)
            cache = item
        else:
            cache += item  
res.append(cache)      
print(res)
```

But I was wondering is there anything in this format:
`re.match(r'(^.{0,2}日)|(^.{0,2}月)', item) and re.match(r'。$', item)` can directly in one loop or some simple regex?

Comment: So if `日` or `月` appear at the start of a substring, then why do you want to keep `11月2日` together in a single element? Same with `BBB。CCC。`. If `。` is the end of a substring, then why concatenate them in a single element? Do you have more specific rules?

Comment: @JvdV thanks for your reply and no other rules,  for example, 1日 or 1月 or 1月1, all of them can regard the start of sub-string, while 。is the end of sub-string.

Comment: With this explaination your desired results seem to be very random. `ZZZ。` is a single element while `BBB。CCC。` are kept together. Very arbitrairy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.split` with

```
(?<=。)(?=\s*\d{1,2}[日月])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A44JBd/4). *Details*:

- `(?<=。)` - match a location right after a dot
- `(?=\s*\d{1,2}[日月])` - that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces, then one or two digits and then a `日` or `月`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/d4I7EX):

```py
import re
text = "ZZZ。10月,AAA。11月2日,BBB。CCC。3日,DDD。EEE。12月，FFF"
print( re.split(r'(?<=。)(?=\s*\d{1,2}[日月])', text) )
# => ['ZZZ。', '10月,AAA。', '11月2日,BBB。CCC。', '3日,DDD。EEE。', '12月，FFF']
```

Comment: But where is limitation of period "。"？

Comment: @4daJKong This is not necessary  judging by your requirements.

Comment: Sorry but "ZZZZZ,10月,AAA。BBB。CCC。" for example,  it should be regard as one sentence."

Comment: @4daJKong So, `re.split(r'(?<=。)(?=\s*\b\d{1,2}[日月])', text)`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, if my string like, "ZZZ。。10月,AAA。" and I want to split it in this format: "ZZZ。。。// 10月,AAA。" I tried to (r'((?<=。。)(?=\s*\b\d{1,2}[日月]))|((?<=。)(?=\s*\b\d{1,2}[日月]))' but it is complicate, and if there are  multi 。here, it is impossible to control...

Comment: @4daJKong I think the [current solution works well](https://regex101.com/r/u4Svhb/1).